# Program to check whether extension of a file is .txt

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser, file-extension

I wrote a java code having an awt text field and a button, where if I click on the button, I can browse a file using JFileChooser. It needs to check whether the file has ".txt" extension or not.I wrote the code below, but it is not getting verified.

Where am I going wrong?  Please help to determine where I am wrong.

```
         try{
            final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
            public String getDescription() {
                return "*.txt";
            }
            public boolean accept(File filename)
            {

                if(filename.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                System.out.println("Browsed dest file extension must be .txt");
                return false;
                }}
            });
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"Exception occurred");
        }
```

Comment: IIRC, accept() must also allow directories. Be aware that, on almost any OS but Windows, the extension is irrelevant, so the user might wish to select a file with no extension or a different one. (In the specific case of plain text files, this may also happen on Windows). Finally, if you really must, try [javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that:

```
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

stop execution of code until user select a file. Add this line after adding `FileFilter` and eveyrthing should work ok.

Little explanation:

Method `showOpenDialog(Component c)` blockexecution of current thread until user action and next line of your code will be executed after the user choose a file. If you invoke after adding a `FileFilter` once again `showOpenDialog` it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using the `@Override` annotation for the `accept` method - see this link [@Override explained in Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Plus, it would be best to use `filename.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")` instead `filename.getName().endsWith(".txt")` to ensure that files with the extension `.TXT` will pass the filter as well.